# Safety of using JWT in Vue-Express app and its implementation

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, security, jwt

So i am making an app with Vue and Express. I wanted to use JWT to authentication.
In the login form the user writes passowrd and email- it get sent to endpoint, if the credensial are correct, the reponse is

```
{
    "status": "successful login!",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY1MTA5NGQzOWE3YjFjNTg2YzA1MDc5YyIsImlhdCI6MTY5NTU5MjQwOCwiZXhwIjoxNzAzMzY4NDA4fQ.DJQVKPtfevTbnjM5IfEPQ0n29S7lN3_Fg4KsFDpwmdE",
    "message": "you are logged in successfully"
}
```

then i store it in LocalStorage.

So now i understand that:

1. In Vue router i use navigation gauards to check if token is in local Storage
2. IF the token is in local storage, the isAuthenticated i set to true and give access to user?
   This doesnt seem safe at all. Or is it? How do I implement a safe auth from this point and restrict access to certain routes?

Comment: It's back end that gives access to a user. It checks a token for all requests. You need to change the status to unauthorized on front end when a token expires or BE responds with 401, but this doesn't affect the safety.